# How to retrieve Git commit id and message in VSTS/TFS build?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops, hockeyapp

I'm in a CI environment using VSTS and I want to get the commit comment to set him into a text file.

Here are my build step : 
[image]

The idea is to copy the GIT commit comment into a text file stored in the artifact folder. Then with the HockeyApp SDK, i'll set my commit comment in the relase note.

I can easily copy the file with a command line operation, but I do not know how the retrieve the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment variable `$(Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)` is set during build. You can access it using `$(build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)` directly in your task inputs.

If you want to access it in a powershell script or inline powershell script. You can access it via the environment variable i.e. `Get-Item Env:\BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE`

The following script will create a new file commit.txt in the binaries folder with commit message in it. Run the script using the Powershell task with inline Type.

```
$message = (Get-Item Env:\BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)

$path =  (Get-Item Env:\BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY).Value + '\commit.txt'

echo $message > $path
```

[image]

Comment: According to your example, I tried with a command line. Tool = `echo`. Arguments = `"$(Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)" > "$(build.binariesdirectory)\$(BuildConfiguration)\drop\commitComment.txt"`. I got the following error : `[warning]File name doesn't indicate a full path to a executable file.`

Comment: I don't think it would work like that. BuildConfiguration variable is not available. Let me formulate an example which works.

Comment: @XavierW. Added the example in the answer which works with VSTS. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Perfect. I add the `.Value` in the message and set the path like that : `$path =  (Get-Item Env:\BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY).Value + '\Release\commit.txt'`. Thanks !

Comment: This works, but retrieves only the message of the last commit. If you push e. g. 3 commits, which trigger a new build, how can you access all of these? In the german version this is shown as "Zugeordnete Änderungen" which could be something like "Related Changes" on the build summary page. Is it possible to access that information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852685/vsts-missing-certain-build-flag-envbuild-sourceversionmessage   Why is Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE missing from my build?

Answer (score 3):

Following command will display the latest commit id and commit message:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | head -1
```

Comment: This is actually the simplest answer. In my case Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE was missing so I simply used "git log head -1"

Comment: This is dependent on the OS, you can use this instead: `git log -1 --pretty=oneline`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a power-shell script task in the build definition to get the commit comment and write it to a text file via [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#get-a-commit).

Comment: I'm not very good in Power-shell. Do you have an example or an article speaking about Power-shell and VSTS working together ?