# VSTS missing certain build flag: env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my Visual Studio Team Services build I am pulling from a bitbucket repo. I am trying to get the commit message and use it in a powershell script.

In my powershell script I have the following code.

```
 param (
    ##Expect to be passed parameter $(Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)
    [string]$commitMessage = ""
 )

Write-Warning "Source Message: $commitMessage"
Write-Warning "SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE: $env:Build_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE"
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
2017-08-24T02:18:27.0938681Z ##[command]. 'd:\a\1\s\Pcmtec.Azure\DeploymentScripts\SetBuildTagTest.ps1' -commitMessage $(Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)

2017-08-24T02:18:30.3970727Z ##[error]Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE : The term 'Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:82
+ ... pts\SetBuildTagTest.ps1' -commitMessage $(Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


2017-08-24T02:18:30.4020718Z WARNING: Source Message: 
2017-08-24T02:18:30.4020718Z WARNING: SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE:
```

It then prints out all the env variables. The only ones I get are:

```
BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY 
BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY        
BUILD_BUILDID                  
BUILD_BUILDNUMBER              
BUILD_BUILDURI                 
BUILD_CONTAINERID              
BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME           
BUILD_DEFINITIONVERSION        
BUILD_QUEUEDBY                 
BUILD_QUEUEDBYID               
BUILD_REASON                   
BUILD_REPOSITORY_CLEAN         
BUILD_REPOSITORY_GIT_SUBMOD... 
BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID            
BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH     
BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME          
BUILD_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER      
BUILD_REPOSITORY_URI           
BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR             
BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL        
BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID           
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH             
BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME         
BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY         
BUILD_SOURCEVERSION            
BUILD_STAGINGDIRECTORY         
BUILDCONFIGURATION
```

Why is BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE missing?

I don't know, but it was reported missing before, [as you noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199473/how-to-retrieve-git-commit-id-and-message-in-vsts-tfs-build#comment78663333_38199969) (and in [mentioned here as well](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2147#issuecomment-324527195)).

I would still use the Git command alternative `git log --format='%s' -1`: if there is no value here either, that would at least give a clue.